# Find all tags at same commit as a given tag in a remote git repository

Tags: git, git-remote, git-tag

I am trying to find all tags that are at the same commit as a given tag in a *remote* git repository. If at all possible, I do not want to clone a local copy of the remote.

For example, I have a repository where the two tags `release/latest` and `release/1.00` both point to the same commit. So, given the tag `release/latest` I want my script to return `release/1.00`.

I am using `ls-remote` to list the remote tags:

```
git ls-remote --tags gitolite@myserver.example.org:/base.git
```

This command returns

```
ad759      refs/tags/release/1.00
0e9d0      refs/tags/release/1.00^{}
de388      refs/tags/release/latest
0e9d0      refs/tags/release/latest^{}
```

(I shortened the commit hashes to save space.)

I do not know how to interpret this: Why are there two lines for each tag? Which reference points to the "real" tags? Should I ignore the tags not followed by `^{}`?

Comment: The first is the ID of the tag, the second is the ID of the commit.  See "git cat-file -t <I'd>"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tags ending with `^{}` are the actual (*lightweight*) tags to git commits; whereas the ones without this suffix are (PGP-)signed or otherwise *annotated* ones.

On a remote repository, you'll have to parse the output of `ls-remote`, like this:

```
tags=$(git ls-remote --tags gitolite@myserver.example.org:/base.git)
REV=$(echo "$tags" | sed -n 's#\s*refs/tags/release/latest$##p')
echo "$tags" | sed -n "s#$REV\s*refs/tags/##p"
```

On a local (1.7.0) repository, you could simply use

```
git tag --points-at release/latest
```

On pre-1.7.0, substitute ls-remote with `git show-ref --tags -d` in the remote solution.

Comment: @GoZoner No, the question is clearly how to find which tags point at one exact commit. `--contains` would list all tags in whose histories the commit occurs.

Comment: Ah, my `git` version is a bit old; doesn't include `--points-at`.

Comment: The `git tag` command works only on a local clone, yes? The repository I want to examine is remote.

Comment: @rlandster git's typical usage model is that you have a clone, and you can get the remote tags with `git fetch --tags`. Updated the answer with a solution for the remote repository as a shell script. Note that if the annotation is a cryptographical signature; the annotated versions will never point to the same object since the tag object contains its own name.